# Дима/Алена выпустила (выпустил? выпустили?) разрешение

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Какой род глагола в случае подобной фразы, когда "Дима ИЛИ Алена выпустил (-а) разрешение?
Если было бы "Дима И Алена", тогда понятно что множественная форма - "выпустили разрешение". А если ИЛИ?

Comment: Расставьте знаки препинания и сразу прояснится. Как расценивать на письме математические знаки типа флеш? Это — дробь?

Comment: В том виде, как вы написали, с (-а) :  если Дима, то выпустил. Если Алёна - то выпустила.  Всё просто :-)

Comment: А что вообще означает " выпустил(-а) разрешение"? Странное словосочетание.

Comment: @МатвейДёмин Это уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Если подлежащие являются словами разного рода, сказуемое употребляется в форме множественного числа: Каждую минуту к остановке подъезжали то автобус, то маршрутное такси (смысловая координация)

Следовательно, так: Дима ИЛИ Алена выпустили разрешение? (оба могли, мн.ч.)

Только фраза получилась какая-то корявая, разговорная, лучше бы перестроить:Кто выпустил разрешение: Дима или Алёна?

Comment: А если "Либо Дима, либо Алена...", то как закончить  фразу?

Comment: Всё равно множественное ч.При однородных подлежащих в  ед. ч., сказуемое ставится в  ед. ч., если:а) подлежащие связаны разделит. союзами и находятся после сказуемого.Искл.: если подлеж. являются словами разного рода;б) если подлежащие связаны противит.союзом а либо союзами не только... но и, не столько...сколько и под., имеющими оттенок противопоставления 1. Не лечение, а отдых необходим ему.
В остальных случаях предпочтительна либо необходима форма мн. ч.

Comment: Но это тоже коряво. Корректно так: Либо Дима выпустил разрешение, либо Алена.